# Azure WebApp how client can see new content without refresh when server is updated with new content

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure-web-app-service, azure-web-roles

I have a webapp on azure, its developed in using ASP.net, JavaScript and Html. Whenever i update my server in background, I expect anybody who is using or the page is already opened, they should see the new content without need to refresh their page. is it possible ?

Comment: SignalR is one solution

Answer (score 0):

AJAX allows easier and quicker interaction between user and website as pages are not reloaded for content to be displayed. We can call ajax function via [setInterval](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp).

```html
setInterval(ajaxCall, 60000); //60000= 1min

function ajaxCall() {
    //do get request and update new content to page
}
```

If that still could not meet your requirement, please try the method that Developer provide. Here is [the document](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-signalr) for you to get started with signalr.